# How to keep images float in the same line?

Tags: html, css

(I'm a fresh newbie-So be gentle)

My images float to a new line instead of staying in one line,
when I change the window size.

How can I keep the inages on the same line?

html

```
<div class="home-boxes">
    <article class="news" >
        <img class="new-img" src="man.png" >
        <span class="main-title">NEWS</span>
    </article>
    <article class="news" >
        <img class="new-img" src="kids2.png" >
        <span class="main-title">KIDS</span>
    </article>
    <article class="news" >
        <img class="new-img" src="babys.png" >
        <span class="main-title">BABIES</span>
    </article>
    <article class="news" >
        <img class="new-img" src="noamt.png" >
        <span class="main-title">BABIES</span>
    </article>      
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.home-boxes {
    position: relative;
    width: 1584px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Impact;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow: auto;
}

.news {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 396px;
    width: 396px;
    display: inline;
}
```

(beware: previous post editing broke some of the CSS code i.e. font - size instead of font-size)

Comment: Try commenting the left:0px; in the .news class.

Comment: add `display:block;` to your `div.home-boxes`

Comment: @sivatumma: Why should he add display: block to a div? It is already a block element.

Answer (score 3):

`Float`ed elements occupy the available view-port area to expand, so when you resize, viewport width reduces and hence they wrap in new line, to avoid this

You can do 2 things :

**first**

either add `white-space:nowrap` to `home-boxes` class, this way it will avoid the images to wrap in next line.

Removing unnecessary css, here is one way => **http://jsfiddle.net/zV7FC/**

**second**

you can add `display:inline-block` to `home-boxes` and `news` class subsequently together!!

Removing unnecessary css, here is another way => **http://jsfiddle.net/zV7FC/1/**

Comment: @NoobEditor tries the first+second solution- didnt work- the images jumps to a new line.

Comment: @user3247816 : please check the fiddle...it seems to work in that!!

Comment: @user3247816 : can you provide a fiddle of your code, the one which is not working????

Comment: @user3247816 : ok....revise me again that, you want `<ul id="navigation">` in one line without wrapping...right???

Comment: yes, but the problem is: wheneber i change the window size, the images goes to next line. the navigator is fine.

Comment: @user3247816 : you have applied excess `css` in your style-sheet....check this fiddle, this solves you problem i guess => http://jsfiddle.net/9f3kX/4/

Comment: @user3247816 : are you talking in reference to above fiddle or did you applied it to ur css and it failed??

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `%` on the width also instead of having it fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/62UN9/2/

```
.news
    {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:25%;
}
```